# About base class in derived class initialization

Tags: c++, constructor

guys. I see several cases like:

```
class Derived:public Base{

public:
    Derived(...):Base(...){}
}
```

Is what situation or is there any principle that we should explicitly initialize the Base in the Derived ctor initialization list? Thanks

Comment: As summary, call base ctor with arguments and designate specific ctor are the commone use for its showing up in initialization list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if we need to pass the arguments of derived constructor to the base constructor, it can be used.

```
class foo
{
    public:
        foo() {} 
        foo( int num ) {}
};

class bar : public foo
{
    public:
        bar(int barNum): foo(barNum) {}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call a base constructor with arguments.

Comment: a constructor that takes arguments is not necessarily a "non-default" constructor.

Comment: Oops... somehow I can't give u upvote... it says you've to edit it once!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple constructor in your base class (basically entry point),
So you have choice to call any of them.

Answer (score 0):

If don't explitily initialize the base class, the default constructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

A good coding standard will recommend you to always initialize base class in the constructor's initialization list.

If the constructor of the base class requires some arguments, then you have to do it.