# C++ , Default constructor

Tags: c++

When a constructor in a superclass receives arguments, it is no longer a default constructor, right?  For example

```
class a {
    public:
      int a;
      int b;
      a(int c, int d){
        cout<<"hello";
      };
}
```

Now when I try to make a subclass, the program causes an error, it says "no default constructor is defined in the super class". How can I solve this problem? I know that if I remove the arguments, everything is going to be fine but I'm told not to do so in my C++ test. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577663/about-base-class-in-derived-class-initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally deal with this with an initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>

class a { 
public:
    a(int c, int d) { std::cout << c << " " << d << "\n"; }
};

class b : public a { 
public:
    b() : a(1, 2) {}
};

int main() { 
    b x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to modify coded, I just have add some extra sub classes for that superclass.

Comment: This does not involve modifying the base class, only the derived class(es). I've included a base class definition above only for completeness, but (for example) the `b` given here should work with the `a` you defined in your question.

Comment: I tried it but visual studio underlined the whole line b() : a(1, 2) {},

Comment: @pouyavedadiyan: I've edited the answer to include the right headers and such so it's complete and compilable. When it runs, the result should be `1 2` -- when you create the `b` object in `main`, that invokes `a(1,2)`, which prints out the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If your base class isn't default-constructible, or if you don't *want* to use the base class's default constructor, then you simply have to *tell* the derived class how to construct the base subobject:

```
struct b : a
{
    b(int n) : a(n, 2*n) { }
    //         ^^^^^^^^^ <--  base class initializer, calls desired constructor
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a constructor which takes no argument yourself.

```
a::a()
{

}
```

Once you provide any constructor for your class the compiler does not generate the implicit default constructor which takes no arguments. So if your code then needs a no arguments constructor you will have to provide it yourself.

Comment: I just tried but it gave me the same error + a new one of a::a(){}. Any idea?

Comment: Please post your code in Question.Unless You show what you tried how can yo be helped?

Comment: I am given a code , I am not allowed to modify it. What I am asked to do is to add two subclasses based on the given super class , the class is something like this :class a {
public :
 int x;
 string h;
 
a (int y, string d){
 
 y=10;
 d="hello";
 cout <<y<<endl<<d;
 };

};